# Error when Trying to copy files from one SharePoint folder to other using Explorer view

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, explorer-view

I am facing one weird issue and have tried all possible ways but with no luck.The issue is when I try to copy certain files in SharePoint folder and paste it in another folder for same site collection using explorer view I get error with three button as Tryagain Skip Cancel for certain files. I tried this with other machines, but no use, all in my team is facing this issue with those file. Below is what i get in Event Viewer.... and there is no proper solution available in Google.... So who can help me now!!!!!

Using SharePoint 2010 and Window 7

Event Viewer:

The description for Event ID 14901 from source WebClient cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

\xyz\xyz.doc

Comment: is the sharepoint url added to the Trusted Sites in IE?

Comment: it is happening for some files..not for all..what that has to do with trusted sites?

Comment: Because it allows a more permissive access to SharePoint (without logon prompts), but are you browsing to the site using the default zone url?

Comment: default zone as in my site url is http:// and not https://.....will try trusted site as well

Comment: well specifically local intranet zone works better if it's an intranet

Answer (score 0):

I know my suggestion is kind of dumb but...
Have you checked the destination path character count? I mean, that classic MS "258 characters limit" stuff.

Sometimes you cant move files because the destination folder path will have more than the maximum character path size limit.

Comment: yes checked..first thing which was checked...its nothing related to file name..

Comment: Okay. These files are not checked-out, right? Any "almost special" characters into the file names, Like "-"? These files are large (50mb+) or just usual office-sized files (1~10mb)?

Comment: No special character ,size 12-13kb file, not checked out.